# Direct Admin change files mutiple domains

Tags: php, file, ssh

On a server with DirectAdmin I host around 80 websites. Now I want to update the CKEditor on every website. This CKEditor is on every website in the same folder. Like: public_html/admin/plugin/CKeditor

Is there any option to make a script or something to upload the new CKEditor to all the domains that has the CKEditor map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script to FTP upload to all of your sites.  You would have to create an array/ list of objects containing your FTP info such as the IP address, user name and password.  Then loop through the object list and upload your files to the correct directory.

You may also want to delete the existing directory.  I would recommend first trying this on a single site to see if the process works.  Then you can try do two or three at a time, and see if there are any errors.  Then, you could run the remaining 70-80.

For example, look at this code taken from the php site:

```
<?php

class SFTPConnection
{
    private $connection;
    private $sftp;

    public function __construct($host, $port=22)
    {
        $this->connection = @ssh2_connect($host, $port);
        if (! $this->connection)
            throw new Exception("Could not connect to $host on port $port.");
    }

    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        if (! @ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $username, $password))
            throw new Exception("Could not authenticate with username $username " .
                                "and password $password.");

        $this->sftp = @ssh2_sftp($this->connection);
        if (! $this->sftp)
            throw new Exception("Could not initialize SFTP subsystem.");
    }

    public function uploadFile($local_file, $remote_file)
    {
        $sftp = $this->sftp;
        $stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$remote_file", 'w');

        if (! $stream)
            throw new Exception("Could not open file: $remote_file");

        $data_to_send = @file_get_contents($local_file);
        if ($data_to_send === false)
            throw new Exception("Could not open local file: $local_file.");

        if (@fwrite($stream, $data_to_send) === false)
            throw new Exception("Could not send data from file: $local_file.");

        @fclose($stream);
    }
}

try
{
    $sftp = new SFTPConnection("localhost", 22);
    $sftp->login("username", "password");
    $sftp->uploadFile("/tmp/to_be_sent", "/tmp/to_be_received");
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

?>
```

Ref. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php#94651

With that, you can login and upload a file.  You would just have to modify this to loop through a list of sites and loop through the entire directory you want to upload.